# how do I properly link GLAD to my project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, linker, glad

I am making a small game engine in Visual Studio. As far as I am aware I have everything linked correctly, but I am still generating this in the .log file

```
Creating library C:\dev\Gluten\Gluten\bin\x64\Release\Gluten.lib and object C:\dev\Gluten\Gluten\bin\x64\Release\Gluten.exp
WindowsWindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol gladLoadGLLoader
C:\dev\Gluten\Gluten\bin\x64\Release\Gluten.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Here is my Additional Include Directories

```
$(SolutionDir)Gluten\vendor\GLAD\include\
```

My Additional Libraries

```
$(SolutionDir)Gluten\vendor\GLAD\lib\
```

And I am including `glad.lib` in my linker input

This is my project structure

[image]

Comment: Is that the only error? Did you get an error that states it can't open `glad.lib`?

Comment: yes, that is the only error. There are no runtime errors only build

Comment: Did you apply the compiler and linker settings to all configurations (Debug, Release ...) instead of just the active configuration? The default behavior is just the active configuration.

Comment: Yes, I am on all configurations and only have one platform, x64

Comment: @DevStuffz I suggest you should add the `glad.c` to your solution.
Go to Visual Studio > Solution Explorer > Source Files > Add > Existing Item ..

Comment: What @DevStuffz said. This is one src file project. I have it with the rest of the source files.Then you don't have any linker headache to sort out.

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT this was correct! please make an answer so I can mark it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you should add the `glad.c` to your solution.

Go to Visual Studio > Solution Explorer > Source Files > Add > Existing Item.

Visual Studio will not automatically recognize the file if you drag 'glad.c' file and drop it into the Source Files.